# Can my recursive query be quicker?

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursive-query

I've written the below recursive query to bring back a chain of leads together starting from the leaf or initial lead and returning all the previous leads.

The end result will be fed into another query that produces one row per chain, i'm not keen on recursive queries in general but i dont see another way to write this.

```
WITH [D1] AS
(
    SELECT 
        [Opp]._Customer_ID [CusID], 
        [Opp].Opportunity_ID [OppID], 
        [Opp].Reference [Ref], 
        [Opp].CoverStartDate_Actual [CoverStart], 
        [Opp].Date_Cancelled [Cancelled], 
        [Opp].Renewal, 
        [Opp]._Product_ID [ProID], 
        [Opp].inf_Opportunity_ID_Prior [PriorOppID], 
        [Opp].Policy_Number [PolicyNo], 
        [Opp].RealOpp [Real], 
        [Opp].Deleted, 
        [Opp].[Status],
        [Prior].Reference as PriorRef, 
        DATEDIFF(MONTH,[Prior].CoverStartDate_Actual,[Opp].CoverStartDate_Actual) as PriorOppMonthsApart, 
        [Prior].Months_Cover as PriorMonthsCover
    FROM 
        dbo.crm_Opportunity [Opp]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.crm_Opportunity [Prior] ON [Prior].Opportunity_ID = [Opp].inf_Opportunity_ID_Prior
    WHERE 
        ([Opp].Deleted = 0) 
        AND ([Opp].[Status] = 5) 
        AND ([Opp].RealOpp = 1)
),
```

This is the initial query to return all the data that we will perform operations on. I could add a TempTable here or Table Varible, to hold this info.

```
[D2] AS
(
    SELECT 
            [D1].OppID, 
            [D1].Ref, 
            [D1].CoverStart, 
            [D1].Cancelled, 
            [D1].Renewal, 
            [D1].ProID, 
            [D1].PriorOppID, 
            [D1].PolicyNo,
            1 AS Depth, 
            [D1].Ref AS TopRef, 
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(7),NULL) AS NextRef, 
            [D1].PriorRef, 
            [D1].PriorOppMonthsApart, 
            [D1].PriorMonthsCover, 
            [Cu].Introducer_Company_ID [Introducer], 
            [D1].OppID AS _Opportunity_ID_Top

    FROM 
            [D1] 
                INNER JOIN dbo.crm_Customer [Cu] ON [D1].CusID = [Cu].Customer_ID

    WHERE 
            ([Cu].Deleted = 0) 
            AND ([Cu]._Company_ID = 'bd164825-a16a-4bee-9b01-6971604dda63')
            AND 
                (
                SELECT 
                    COUNT(*) 
                FROM 
                    ACTIVEQUOTE.dbo.crm_Opportunity op2 
                WHERE 
                    ([D1].[PriorOppID] = [D1].OppID)
                    AND ([D1].Deleted = 0) 
                    AND ([D1].[Status] IN (2,3,4,5))
                ) = 0

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
            [D1].OppID, 
            [D1].[Ref], 
            [D1].[CoverStart],
            [D1].[Cancelled], 
            [D1].Renewal, 
            [D1].[ProID], 
            [D1].PriorOppID, 
            [D1].PolicyNo,
            [D2].Depth + 1 as Depth, 
            [D2].TopRef, 
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(7),[D2].Ref) as NextRef, 
            [D1].PriorRef, 
            [D1].PriorOppMonthsApart, 
            [D1].PriorMonthsCover, 
            [D2].[Introducer], 
            [D2]._Opportunity_ID_Top

    FROM 
        [D1] 
            INNER JOIN [D2] ON [D1].OppID = [D2].PriorOppID
),
```

Welcome to recursive hell, as i said i'm not a fan of recursive queries but it was the only way i could use to feed back up the chain per say. The query takes the prior lead reference and returns it until it comes to leads with a NULL prior lead.

```
[D3] AS
(
SELECT  
        [D2].[ProID], 
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY TopRef) AS Years, 
        [D2].Depth,
        [D2].TopRef, 
        [D2].Ref, 
        [D2].NextRef, 
        [D2].PriorRef, 
        CASE WHEN [D2].[PriorRef] IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS OriginOpp,
        [D2].Renewal,
        [D2].OppID,  
        [D2].CoverStart, 
        [D2].Cancelled,  
        [D2].PolicyNo, 
        [D2].PriorOppMonthsApart, 
        [D2].PriorMonthsCover,
        [D2].Introducer,
        [D2]._Opportunity_ID_Top
FROM 
        [D2]
)

SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    [D3]
```

The final piece of the puzzle is to format the data into usable rows, the PARTITION is used to determine how old the sale is.

Then i select everything.

Comment: So your question is "can i make this quicker"? if so, quicker than what? is it slow? how fast do you expect it to be? have you checked the execution plan? At present, your question is a lot of SQL for people to read and digest, can you not simplify and add some dummy data so that people can perhaps replicate the query execution?

Comment: Valid points @Tanner, I suppose what i want to know is if my solution is the most efficient way to write the query. I do need to look at index tuning etc, but i wanted to ensure that my SQL was top notch before looking at DB improvements.
I will create and add a dummy dataset as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Your inner query for Count = 0 is not correlated.  You're counting all the rows in Opportunity when D1 criteria is met.

```
  WHERE 
            ...
            AND 
                (
                SELECT 
                    COUNT(*) 
                FROM 
                    ACTIVEQUOTE.dbo.crm_Opportunity op2 
                WHERE 
                    ([D1].[PriorOppID] = [D1].OppID)
                    AND ([D1].Deleted = 0) 
                    AND ([D1].[Status] IN (2,3,4,5))
                    --Should there be a relationship between op2 and D1?
                ) = 0
```

Should the Opportunity have a relationship to D1?  Otherwise, you could speed this up by putting the Opportunity count into a variable.